# Iterate through two array of arrays and run function on every arrays and create a new array with function result

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

i have these two array of arrays (hi everyone, dont know why it doesnt print "hi everyone" at the start of paragraph)

`MyArray1=[["jack", 0],["daniel", 2] ["sam", 1] ]`

and this one `MyArray2=[["jack", 0],["daniel", 10] ["sam", 2] ]`

You see here there are sames values in both arrays, i would like to run a function that just adds two elements (it can be division also or substraction doesnt matter)

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
  return a + b;}
```

And returns a new array with this where the math is done

`finalArray=[["jack", 0],["daniel", 12] ["sam", 3] ]`

I know how to do it on two simple arrays but on array of arrays i'm lost.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here to get the total as:

```
MyArray1.map(([str, num], index) => [str, num + MyArray2[index][1],])
```

When you map over an array then you have to pass a callback function that will receive arguments as:

> *Array.prototyep.map*
>
> **`callbackFn Function`**: that is called for every element of arr. Each time
> callbackFn executes, the returned value is added to newArray.
>
> The function is called with the following arguments:
>
> **`element`**: The current element being processed in the array.
>
> **`index`**: The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> **`array`**: The array map was called upon.
>
> **`thisArg (Optional)`**: Value to use as this when executing callbackFn.

So you can use `index` of current array and get the value from second array using same `index`

```js
const MyArray1 = [
    ['jack', 0],
    ['daniel', 2],
    ['sam', 1],
];
const MyArray2 = [
    ['jack', 0],
    ['daniel', 10],
    ['sam', 2],
];

const result = MyArray1.map(([str, num], index) => [
    str,
    num + MyArray2[index][1]
]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have generalized upon the answer of @NullPointerException.

```js
const MyArray1 = [
  ['jack', 0],
  ['daniel', 2],
  ['sam', 1],
];
const MyArray2 = [
  ['jack', 0],
  ['daniel', 10],
  ['sam', 2],
];


var add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function apply_array(func, MyArray1, MyArray2) {
  const result = MyArray1.map(([str, num], index) => [
    str,
    func(num, MyArray2[index][1])
  ]);
  return result;
}

console.log(apply_array(add, MyArray1, MyArray2));
```